# Error Occurs While Updating an Array Element for a Property inside Service

Tags: ember.js

```
export default Ember.Service.extend({
    currentQuizIndex: 0,
    quizzes: [
        {
            answer: '',
            inspected: true,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image0.jpg'
        },
        {
            answer: '',
            inspected: true,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image1.jpg'
        },
        {
            answer: '',
            inspected: false,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image2.jpg'
        }
    ],

...
```

I would like to update the image selected state by providing an index, so I declare the following function,

```
highLightQuiz(index) {
    const target = this.get('quizzes').objectAt(index);
    console.log(target);  // DO produce the desired target element
    target.set('selected', true);
},
```

However, it produce an Uncaught TypeError (see below)

```
quiz-list.js:78 Uncaught TypeError: target.set is not a function
    at Class.highLightQuiz (quiz-list.js:78)
    at Class.click (image-thumbnail.js:87)
    at Class.trigger (ember.debug.js:41454)
    at Class.superWrapper [as trigger] (ember.debug.js:39636)
    at Backburner.run (ember.debug.js:720)
    at Backburner.join (ember.debug.js:746)
    at Function.run.join (ember.debug.js:21556)
    at ember.debug.js:41584
    at Object.flaggedInstrument (ember.debug.js:17747)
    at Object.handleEvent (ember.debug.js:41583)
```

In the console, I can see there is a method called `set selected: GETTER_FUNCTION()`. Did I miss anything?

[image]

Comment: instead of `get` use `objectAt`  I mean `this.get('quizzes').objectAt('1')

Comment: @kumkanillam the result is the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve array content at the given index,

```
highLightQuiz(index) {
    let temp = this.get('quizzes').objectAt(index);
    console.log(temp);  // ensure target element exists
    Ember.set(temp,'selected',true)
}
```

[Reference](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Array.html#method_objectAt)

EDIT: Reason for the error is, 
`quizzes` array contains normal JS object. if it is `Ember.Object` then you will be able to access `get` and `set` function on the properties.

Your code will work if you got `quizzes` property initialized like below,

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Service.extend({ 
  currentQuizIndex: 0,
  quizzes: [
        Ember.Object.create({
            answer: '',
            inspected: true,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image0.jpg'
        }),
        Ember.Object.create({
            answer: '',
            inspected: true,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image1.jpg'
        }),
        Ember.Object.create({
            answer: '',
            inspected: false,
            rects: [],
            selected: false,
            src: '/assets/images/sample-image2.jpg'
        })
    ],
  highLightQuiz(index) {
    const target = this.get('quizzes').objectAt(index);
    console.log(target);  // DO produce the desired target element
    target.set('selected', true);
    console.log(' target ',target);
},
});
```

Comment: element does exist, but I get `target.set is not a function` TypeError.

Comment: please try this `Ember.set(temp,'selected',true)`

Comment: It works! Thank you @kumkanillam. Could you please update your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: But objectAt also should work..I will try it ember-twiddle and update the sample